# Navigating from xamarin android to PCL

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am currently using xamarin form with PCL to accessing camera and scan barcodes and show it in a UserDialog . I can do that easily using dependency service. The issue I am having is going back. I want to go back to the PCL by pressing the cancel button on the userDialog. I am using messagingcenter to go back to PCL home page and the message do go back but the UI stay the same i.e the camera screen stays there.

Below is my code

```
void HandleScanResult(ZXing.Result result)
{
    if (result != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Text))
    {
        CrossVibrate.Current.Vibration(500);
    }

    Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
        resultText.Text = await SaveScannedRecord(result.Text);
        PromptResult promptResult = await UserDialogs.Instance.PromptAsync
        ("Hello Friends","Question","SCAN","CANCEL",resultText.Text,InputType.Name);     
        if (promptResult.Ok)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            //CODE TO GO BACK
            var home = new Home();
            RunOnUiThread(() => { xamarinForm.MessagingCenter.Send<Home>(home, "scannedResult"); });

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sending a message to another page just sends a message: you need to do something when you receive the message to dismissing the scanner page.  How you do that would depend on how you displayed it in the first place.  You also have RunOnUIThread nested inside BeginInvokeOnMainThread, which is unnecessary.  Finally, you should be able to call ZXIng directly from PCL.  See the github page for a Forms sample app that does this.

Comment: How do you dismiss the scanner page.

Comment: It depends - you haven't shown the code that actually displays the page.

Comment: I am calling it from PCL class (Home class) using Dependency Service.                                                IBarcodeScanner scanner = DependencyService.Get<IBarcodeScanner>();                                                                            scanner.Scan(config.ScannerKey, config.ServiceUrl);

Comment: In the samples it appears to be dismissing the Scan view automatically.  I'm not sure what you're doing wrong.  I'd try awaiting the Scan method, or using the Forms version of the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such situations, I really like to use `async/await` syntax:

1) Define somewhere in class `TaskCompletionSource<bool>` variable

2) When you call your method, initialize that variable:

```
public async Task<bool> Scan()
{
   // init task variable
   tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

   // call your method for scan (from ZXing lib)
   StartScan(); 

   // return task from source
   return tsc.Task;
}
```

3) When handle result, set result for task:

```
void HandleScanResult(ZXing.Result result)
{
   Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
   {
       resultText.Text = await SaveScannedRecord(result.Text);
       PromptResult promptResult = await UserDialogs.Instance.PromptAsync("Hello Friends", "Question", "SCAN", "CANCEL", resultText.Text, InputType.Name);
       if (promptResult.Ok)
       {
         tsc.SetResult(true);
       }
       else
       {
         //CODE TO GO BACK
         tsc.SetResult(false);
       }
    });    
}
```

Now you can write navigation logic in PCL, like that:

```
var scanResult = await scanService.Scan();
if (!scanResult)
   // your navigation logic goes here
   Navigation.PopToRoot();
```

Comment: I tried your code. But it does go back to PCL page.

Comment: @maxspan there was an error in "code to go back" section. Should be tsc.SetResult(false). Also, I don't really understand what do you want to achieve. I just wanted to point that there is a way to move navigation logic to PCL

Answer (score 0):

@Eugene Solution is a great one, nevertheless you can still use the Messaging center:

I believe the problem is right here:

```
xamarinForm.MessagingCenter.Send<Home>(home, "scannedResult"); });

//Solution:
MessagingCenter.Send<Home> (this, "scannedResult");
//Inside the PCL you will need:
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Home> (this, "scannedResult", (sender) => {
    // do your thing.
});
```

Comment: I have already tried that it doesnot work. Also I am using continuously scan.